# numpy array of arbitrary precision (10 bit int)

Tags: python, numpy, int, precision

I need to simulate a piece of hardware that generates binary files where each word is 10 bits. How can I achieve this with a numpy array?

Something like:

```
outarray = np.zeros(512, dtype=np.int10)
```

Thanks!

Comment: No, numpy does not support a 10-bit integer type, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: You can construct 16-bit arrays and just ignore the top 6 bits.

Comment: OK, so to clarify:

What I need at the end is a binary file where each value is 10 bits. Is there a way to do this? So if I have 100 values I need the file to be 1000 bits long at the end of the day to match the hardware.

Comment: So, is your question about 10 bit operations or 10 bit output data (or both)?

Comment: You might find the [bitarray](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray) package useful.

Comment: All I really care about is the output - I am reading in data from another source into a numpy array and I need to just pass it right back out as a binary file with 10 bit precision, I don't need to do any actual operations on the data.

Comment: So, you need to generate a bitstring (and code it as bytes, I assume)? Are your numbers little endian or big endian?

Comment: I suppose that is true - I just need to turn a numpy array of ints into a bitstring and code it as bytes, encoded little endian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numpy doesn't have an `uint10` type. But you can use `uint16`, and a bitmask to check for overflow. And use `binary_rep` to get the 10 bit binary representations:

```
import numpy as np

MAX_WORD = 2**10
unused_bits = ~np.array([MAX_WORD-1], dtype="uint16")  # Binary mask of the 6 unused_bits

words = np.random.randint(MAX_WORD, size=10, dtype="uint16")  #  Create 10 bit words
assert not np.any(words & unused_bits)  # Check for overflow
for word in words:
    print(word, np.binary_repr(word, width=10))  # Get 10 bit binary representation

binary_repr = "".join(np.binary_repr(word, width=10) for word in words)
print(binary_repr)  # Full binary representation
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option you could consider, if you're mainly interested in understanding the accuracy of arithmetic operations on 10-bit numbers, is to use the [spfpm](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/spfpm/1.2) package. This will simulate the effect of fixed-point arithemetic operations, including multiplication, division, square-roots, trigonometric functions, etc., but doesn't currently support matrix operations.